# How do I create an encrypted ubuntu startup disk?

Tags: usb, startup

So what I'm trying to figure out is how to create an encrypted USB drive I can run Ubuntu from.

This would allow me to carry all of my files and my own operating system in my pocket. If I loose it, nothing is compromised and I can run it on most PC machines. I suppose one approach might be to use my current startup USB stick.

I could temporarily unplug my hard drive and use a second stick as the install target.Am I missing anything? Is there a better way?

I'm also wondering if maybe the startup sticks are special such that they will be more likely to run from most machines than a regular install.  That might put a fly in my ointment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to install Ubuntu as you do on a Hard drive.

**You should remove your current HDD(s) to do the following !**

When the installer asks you the [installation type](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall#Installation_type), select "Erase disks" and check "Encrypt the new ubuntu installation" option.

Then proceed like any other Ubuntu installation !

Comment: I've ordered a 128 Gb flash drive which arrives tomorrow. Then I will give this a try.

Comment: This worked like a charm with the exceptions that it was dog slow and... IDK there might have been some issues with UEFI but I was able to boot.  Conclusion: I'm still not giving up my laptop.

Comment: I think it's because of the usb ... It is handled differently than a real HDD ...

Comment: Well yeah but imagine that combined with encryption. Double wammy.